# First option in a dropdown shows blank in IE9

Tags: html

I came across with a strange error in IE9.

Here is the drop down code:

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

If I don't mention 'selected' for the first option of the dropdown, it still gets selected across all other browsers except IE9. Even it works in IE8.

Is this a bug or do I have to mention 'selected' for the first option??

Could someone help me please??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad I was doing a mistake. I was selecting the option values on the page load based on what the user has selected previously. If the user has not selected anything then in that case the
'selectedVal' was blank and hence causing issues.

I have modified the code like below and it's works absolutely fine now.

```
var selectedVal = userselectedval || 1;
$("select").val(selectedVal);
```

Thanks for all your quick responses!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should mention as select for the first option.
Otherwise, it will just shows the option but not selected.

Answer (score 1):

If IE 9 really behaves that way (I don’t have IE 9, and the issue does not exist in IE 11 when using IE 9 emulation mode), then it’s indeed odd, but technically not a bug. The HTML 4.01 spec says about [preselected options](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#edef-SELECT):

> If no OPTION element has the selected attribute set, user agent
>   behavior for choosing which option is initially selected is undefined.
>   Note. Since existing implementations handle this case differently, the
>   current specification differs from RFC 1866 ([RFC1866] section 8.1.3),
>   which states:
>
> > The initial state has the first option selected, unless a SELECTED attribute is present on any of the  elements.
>
> Since user agent behavior differs, authors should ensure that each
>   menu includes a default pre-selected OPTION.

That’s from year 1999, and browsers have generally adopted the principle of making the first option preselected, if there is `selected` attribute. But it is still safest to use the `selected` attribute.

If you do *not* want *any* option to be initially selected, insert an empty option element at the start:

```
<select name=foo>
  <option></option>
  <option>1
  <option>2
  ...
</select>
```

Your client-side and server-side code for processing must then check for the value being empty and handle the situation suitably – it means that the user did not make any selection, and you can then accept this or handle it as an error condition.